# Networkx: Update single attribute of all nodes within a graph without for loop

Tags: python, networkx

I have some code that can update a **graph**'s attribute:

```
import networkx as nx

def update_nodes(graph):
    values = dict.fromkeys(graph.nodes, True)
    nx.set_node_attributes(graph, name='test_attribute', values=values)
    print(f"graph.nodes.data(): {graph.nodes.data()}")
    return graph

def loop(graph):
    graph.graph['test_attribute'] = False
    print(f"graph.nodes.data(): {graph.nodes.data()}")
    print(f"graph.graph['test_attribute']: {graph.graph['test_attribute']}")
    for node in range(0, len(graph.nodes)):
        print(f"graph.nodes[node]['test_attribute']: {graph.nodes[node]['test_attribute']}")
    return graph

graph = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(n = 3, p = 0.1, seed = 5)
for i in range(0, 2):
    graph = update_nodes(graph)
    graph = loop(graph)
```

This doesn't update the node attribute, and instead applies the update to the graph as a separate entity. Is there any way to mass-update a single attribute of an entire set of nodes without sticking in `for node in (range(0, len(graph.nodes)): graph.nodes[node]['test_attribute'] = <new_value>` somewhere?

Edit: I should've clarified that the reason I'm unhappy with this iteration over the graph's contents is that this initial value needs to be reset for all nodes prior to the running of a second loop after this that calls into question the value of the attribute and follows different logical paths based on that. So I'm hoping to avoid iterating over all nodes twice, albeit this first loop is much less computationally intensive and hopefully unnecessary.

Comment: What's so wrong with this clear, understandable 2-lines simple `for` loop?

Comment: You could just simplify that loop to `for node in graph.nodes: node['test_attribute'] = <new_value>` instead of iterating indexes...

Comment: That's already an improvement thanks, but the inclination for leaning away from the for loop if possible was the result of staring at [this doc](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html#graph-attributes) for too long and thinking that the mass update via `graph.graph['test_attribute'] = <new_value>` might be possible somehow. I find I rely on for loops too much, and was hoping there would be something to replace it with in cases such as this!

Comment: Unfortunately the above suggestion didn't work as `graph.nodes` is treated as a list of ints representing node indices e.g. `[0, 1, 2, ...]`, so I left the loop's use of range()  as-is. I couldn't find a less computationally-intensive solution (not that the for loop is), and as far as cleanliness goes the best I could come up with was moving the 'reset' loop to a separate method and calling it as such instead. Thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set the attribute for all nodes to the same value, you can use `graph.add_nodes_from(graph.nodes,attribute_name='attribute_value')`

This updates the provided attribute (adds the node and attribute if non-existent) but maintains any other node attributes and edges you already have in the graph. See the example below:

```
import networkx as nx

graph = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(n = 3, p = 0.1, seed = 5)

# setup some initial attributes
graph.nodes[0]['attr1'] = 'foo'
graph.nodes[1]['attr1'] = 'bar'
graph.nodes[2]['attr1'] = 'baz'

# make some attribute we want to change
for node in graph.nodes:
    graph.nodes[node]['attr_to_change'] = 'orig_value'

# View initial attribute values
print(graph.nodes(data=True))
# [(0, {'attr1': 'foo', 'attr_to_change': 'orig_value'}),
#  (1, {'attr1': 'bar', 'attr_to_change': 'orig_value'}),
#  (2, {'attr1': 'baz', 'attr_to_change': 'orig_value'})]

# change the value of the attr_to_change attribute for all
graph.add_nodes_from(graph.nodes,attr_to_change='new_value')

# View updated attribute value
print(graph.nodes(data=True))
# [(0, {'attr1': 'foo', 'attr_to_change': 'new_value'}),
#  (1, {'attr1': 'bar', 'attr_to_change': 'new_value'}),
#  (2, {'attr1': 'baz', 'attr_to_change': 'new_value'})]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The [doc](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.add_nodes_from.html) doesn't seem clear, but the `str` passed into the `**attr` parameter holds significance to the node as a reference to a specific value of a k/v dict connected to the set of nodes? Running the command in your answer seems to produce the same issue that my initial use of `graph.graph['attribute_value'] = <value>`, which is the creation of a new, parallel graph that despite having the correct value, doesn't bear reference to the nodes iterated through later.

Comment: I'm confused by the difference between `graph.nodes[index]` not possessing the attribute update from `graph.add_nodes_from(graph.nodes, attribute_name='attribute_value')` though - this isn't an essential problem at all so I wouldn't worry too much, more just a very minor convenience!

Comment: The `**attr` parameter lets you provide a set of attribute_name, attribute_value pairs to assign to all the nodes you provide to the `nodes_for_adding` parameter. In the new example I change the value of the `attr_to_change` attribute to `"new_value"` for all the nodes. Notice in the print the node data that this attribute has been updated but the other attribute remains the same

Comment: What a perfect explanation. This solves the issue exactly as intended. A single line that not only replaces the for loop, but replaces the method containing the for loop (for cleanliness), and an earlier attempted re-assignment not shown in the example code. The best solutions are always the simplest, thanks for the assist!